# Click of Button doing postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Iam using MS Visual developer 2010 Express Edition (Free).

I have a repeater control with toggle function with edit,update,save Link buttons.Every thing was working fine until today

Now I changed the appearence of LINK buttons to Buttons(by setting border style to outset,colour..etc) inside the repeater and added image buttons instead of other buttons outside the repeater.I have used vb.net ,Javascript for doing various functions

And my issue is when ever i click a button,image button or even a link button inside the repeater the form is doing a post back.How can i stop the postback in this case.It looks like flashing for each click of button.How can i resolve this issue

Requesting for help..
Thanks

Comment: Property of the button UseSubmitBehaviour = False?

Answer (score 0):

add to the asp control: `OnClientClick="return false;"`

this will prevent the postback.

hope that helps.

Comment: js functions? or server side functions?

Comment: For toggle function in the repeater i used js function.For all other buutons use vb.net .                                          If e.CommandName = "cancel" Then

            DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox1"), TextBox).Enabled = False

Comment: if you have binded methods on server side you can't prevent postback. it will prevent these methods firing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  `return false;`  in that button `onclick` and `onclientclick` event

see this sample's like

Add *onclick="return false;"* in link button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="someID" onclick="return false;" runat="server" Text="clicky"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The image button have , set  `return false;`

```
<asp:imagebutton OnClientClick="YourFunction(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined is showing on doing this in image button

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        document.getElementById('textbox16.text').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }


</script>

Comment: Try it

    `document.getElementById("<%= textbox16.ClientID %>").style.visibility = 'visible'; } `

Comment: Now your question is `Click of Button doing postback` , this is finished ? if this fixed ,then create new question for new issue, please don't ask many question in this same question, do create new question !!

Comment: Not fixed yet.I have more server side functions.